# Footnotes not working with linguex and leipzig package

Tags: footnotes, linguistics, linguex, leipzig

The question says it all. I am using package `leipzig` for glossing and `linguex` for examples. This is the code.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex. \gll abcd efgh mnop\\
abcd.1.SG.FEM efgh.3.PL.MSC mnop\footnote{This is a verb.}.IMFV.AGR.1.SG.FEM\\
abcd efgh ijkl mnop\\

\end{document}
```

---

PS - This code doesn't give any error in the `beamer` class. Footnote is still not coming, but at least the document gets compiled. In the `article` class it is not the case.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex. \gll abcd efgh mnop\\
abcd.1.SG.FEM efgh.3.PL.MSC mnop\footnote{This is a verb.}.IMFV.AGR.1.SG.FEM\\
abcd efgh ijkl mnop\\


\end{document}
```

---

Actually in one presentation with a similar text I got a footnote also. (I don't know how :P) I'll add a screenshot of the slide and the preamble if needed.

Comment: Three things: 1. The double backslash in the third line of your example is not necessary as you're only using ``gll``, not ``glll``. 2. Do not use ``\footnote`` inside the input of ``gll`` unles you enclose it in a ``savenotes``environment (see package ``footnote``) or use ``\footnotemark`` and ``\footnotetext{<text>}``. 3. ``leipzig`` has nothing to do with the error you encounter.

Comment: Ok, but why does it come in the beamer and not in the article?